# java What action should be considerd for button using as a browse to attach file or directory

Tags: java

I make a JFrame form which contains two text fields and two buttons. 
I need this form works as
when user clicks first button will browse to attach file 
and second button will browse to attach directory.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/uploads/2556c33f29.png

Answer (score 1):

For browse a specified file or directory you should use the  JFileChooser class.

```
    JFileChooser fileChooser = new JFileChooser(".");
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.DIRECTORIES_ONLY); // for directory
fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(JFileChooser.FILES_ONLY); // for files
```

Comment: Please i need more clarification
you need to create class with JFileChooser name
added events according to each button in the form